# Beam Java Dataflow, Bigquery streaming insert GroupByKey reducing elements

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Fairly new to Dataflow/Apache Beam.

I have a pipeline that is reading messages from PubSub, these messages hold a file name for a file in GCS. These are read out of storage, table rows are created from the individual files then streamed into BigQuery.
The problem is, occured inside the streaming insert step, there is a GroupByKey step, this is taking in 20,819 elements, but is emitting considerably less elements at 11,207 [image: GroupByKey input and output]

And we observe 11,207 records inserted into BigQuery.

```
    .apply(String.format(Constants.STREAM_DATA, tableTagName),
BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(table).withExtendedErrorInfo().withoutValidation)
.withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
.withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors()))
```

From reading, can't see how to "modify" step, the pipeline up to this point handles records "as expected".  We read messages from PubSub withIdAttribute to see if that helps, but to no avail.  We mostly observe this when the number of workers increase and the pipeline is under load, but haven't been able to bottom out what's causing it/ how to resolve?

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is related to the Aggregation you're trying to perform... 
Did you try something like "CoGroupByKey" ?
What result are you actually expecting to get from the aggregated data ?

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/cogroupbykey/

Comment: May highlight my lack of knowledge, but not actively Aggregating- it's desired that each message is processed independently.  Not sure what CoGroupByKey would achive as the 20,819 elements at input are the desired number of rows to be inserted?

Comment: If this is actually reducing the number of elements it's probably a bug in the Reshuffle implementation. The GroupByKey there is an expected part of a Reshuffle and can occasionally aggregate elements together (Reshuffle assigns random keys, so there can be duplicates). But the later steps of the Reshuffle should be expanding the elements and dropping the keys, meaning the end result of the Reshuffle should be unchanged. Can you check whether the full Reshuffle transform still outputs 11,207 elements?

Comment: Yes, the overall Reshuffle step outputs 11,207 elements.  Have run multiple cases/ setups, in each what's seen as an output of GroupByKey is what's observed as the output of the overall Reshuffle step.  If it helps(?) we're only observing this in Dataflows that we're allowing to autoscale?

Comment: Can you try setting `ignoreInsertIds` to False in BigqueryIO and see if that works. Documentation can be found here - https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.20.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#ignoreInsertIds--

Comment: @LPD Definitely sounds like a bug then. Are you able to run this pipeline (or a simplified version) on another runner to replicate the behavior? That would help pinpoint if this is a bug in Dataflow or Beam and figure out where to get support.

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman- have tried setting ignoreInsertIds, still dropping messages.

Comment: @DanielOliveira- have tried on direct runner, but this only seems to occur at load, and it just struggles to "survive".  Have raised with Google support.